# Why is “alle” used in “Diese Busse fahren *alle* fünfzehn Minuten” instead of “jede”?

Tags: difference, meaning-in-context, pronoun

I think in the following sentence, *alle* should be replaced with *jede:*

> Diese Busse fahren **alle** fünfzehn Minuten vom Hauptbahnhof ab.

It means that the buses leave **every** fifteen minutes, doesn't it? Are both correct? Do they mean exactly the same?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You use *alle* for "15 minutes" because "minutes" is plural. You would use *jede* for singulars, like *jede halbe Stunde*. You could not use them vice-versa.

Comment: Though I think "alle halbe Stunde" is used colloquially.

Comment: IMHO there's almost no difference between "alle halbe Stunde" and "alle dreißig Minuten". And i doubt whether this is colloquial - i can't think of a situation where this phrase would be inappropriate (maybe simply because i can't think of an alternative ;) ).

Comment: "Alle halbe Stunde" sounds wrong to me, I would say "jede halbe Stunde" or "alle halben Stunden".

Comment: "alle halbe Stunde" does not sound wrong at all to this native German. But it is col. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think it is something like a **fixed term**.

[dwds](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=all&submit_button=Suche&view=1) says

```
alle bezeichnet den wiederkehrenden Wechsel; immer wieder nach  
alle halbe(n), alle (drei) Stunden

mitteldeutsch aller
aller fünf Minuten, zwei Jahre, drei Schritt
```